# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…)

Tags: class, select, selection

Trying to add class to only selected paragraphs in WordPress Editor.
Added a button called 'Add stylish `'<li>'` where there is an item called 'Includes'. So my need is to add class to the selected '`<p>`' when 'Includes' is pressed. Any help will be really grateful. Thanks!

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('sanjog_custom_tinymce_button', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton( 'sanjog_custom_tinymce_button', {
            title: 'Add stylish <li>',
            type: 'menubutton',
            fixedWidth: true,
            icon: 'icon dashicons-menu',
            menu: [
                    {
                        text: 'Includes',
                        onclick: function() {
                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select('p'),'test');                 
                        }
                    },
               ]

        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: any solutions? I am facing the same problem!!